# Django/Python sorting after getting cached results

Tags: python, django, sorting, memcached

Greetings,

A few quick things (django 1.2.3, python 2.6, memcached).

I have a function where I first do a somewhat expensive query,  when I do this query I do an oder_by. I then update some values which may change the order of the results. I then put all of the values in the cache.

Then in another function I get the cache and I want to resort the results so that they are again in order.

so this would be something like.

```
function 1():
    mylist = myevent.people.order_by('-score')
    ....do up date....
    cache.set(cache_key,mylist)

function(2):
    my_cache_list = cache.get(cache_key)
    newlist = sorted(my_cache_list,key=operator.attrgetter('score'), reverse=True )
```

---

based on other posts I would think this should work but I get a typeerror saying that my_cache_list is unsubsriptable.

Anyone have any ideas? Im probably doing something stupid....

thanks.

NOTE: Update made change operator.attrgetter for operator.itemgetter removed error! This code above does work. The problem was in using the operator.itemgetter.

Comment: What does `my_cache_list` equals to when the error appears? May be it's `None`, because there is no cached value? And it's better to store `list` in cache, not queryset.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? When you apply a new condition to an already cached queryset it will do new database query since it need to reevaluate the queryset. Better you save the results of the queryset as a list and then sort them via Python instead of Django's query api.

Comment: @DrTyrsa Why is it better to cache a list than a queryset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python function `sorted()` works with Mutable List Types, which a Django queryset is not: this is what the error you're getting is basically telling you. Technically, subscripting is the act of accessing a list element by its index, like this:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list[0] # This is a subscript
```

If you try that on a queryset, it will fail with the same exception you got:

```
list = MyModel.objects.all()
list[0] # This subscript will fail: a queryset doesn't support the operation
```

If you want to keep your scheme of loading an ordered queryset, caching the results and reordering them on cache access, you will have to turn your queryset into a real list and store that in cache (this will take a lot more cache space, though). In your function 1:

```
qs = myevent.people.order_by('-score')
mylist = list(qs.all())
....do up date....
cache.set(cache_key, mylist)
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, and I think you are right. Do you have a suggestion for how to implement what I am trying to do? do you think really turning it into a true list is a good idea?

Comment: I don't really think I can answer without more information and some (or probably a lot of) benchmarking. BUT... If the sorder needs to be computed at each cache access, a database sort on an indexed field is probably going to be faster than a Python sort. And if the sort order stays stable across cache accesses, it is better to sort the list before caching it.

Comment: @tawmas - I have a high load application so I was trying to minimize connections to the DB and maximize memcached usage. The problem is that there are two places in the code where the cache is need. 1) Where I update scores and 2) Where I want to setup the view for the template to display the scores. I was trying to use the same cache for both operations  but maybe its worthwhile to create a sorted list after the update and cache that as several have suggested.

Comment: What makes you feel that queryset doesn't support this operation? [It does](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) and it's not very difficult to check it yourself.

Comment: @DrTyrsa Your comment here is a vague. Which operation are you referring to. After the initial Entry.objects.order_by('headline'). If you try to order it by a different field or by reverse order nothing happens. I have tried that. I will look at it again and post back if its different.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I have tried that and you get an assention error that you can not reorder a query once its been sliced. The problem that I was originally taking on was that after I did the query with a sort via order_by values change. This will change the order of the objects in the queryset. So now the challenge how to reorder. From above the solution seems to be turn it into a list and sort.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: That is slicing, which is indeed a form of subscripting but not the one needed for sorted() to work (if you're not convinced, try my code in a django shell with any model class you have available and watch for the exception)

Comment: @Tawmas -  It turns out although what you were saying makes sense when I tried it produced the same errors. What removed the error was changing the operator.itemgetter with operator.attrgetter. I could infact no conver the queryset to a list and sorted method works no errors.

Comment: @Tawmas I tried `lst[0]` and it returned the first item in queryset. Actually it's the most obvious way to get the first item. And it's documented. I'd rather quote it: "To retrieve a single object rather than a list (e.g. SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 1), use a simple index instead of a slice".

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that jumps out from your example code. You seem to be treating your cache as a reliable datastore. You should never assume that the cache will return a value.

`my_cache_list` is probably `None` when you're getting the `TypeError`, which means that the cache key was not found. You should always test for a `None` value and regenerate the value.

As you're using the memcache backened you need to remember that you can only store values up to 1MB in size. Values larger than this are silently discarded.

Comment: You are correct on several points. but just a follow up on a few things. 1) This was only an example code set, in the real code if there is no cache I do a db query and then create the cache. 2) I know the results are relatively small. but I do have a high load application so I am trying to mininmize any DB hits that I can.  3) Im sure that there are things in the cache because if I skip what I am trying to do it does display things.

Answer (score -1):

try to pickle your list before you set it in cache:

```
import cPickle as pickle

cache.set(pickle.dumps(mylist))


function(2):
    my_cache_list = cache.get(cache_key)
    newlist = sorted(pickle.loads(my_cache_list),key=operator.itemgetter('score'), reverse=True )
```

Comment: You don't need to pickle a value before putting it in the cache, that is handled for you.